# How to run NSTimer more than 180sec in background?

Tags: ios, iphone

I had integrated pedometer and i am doing some calculation when the app is on background. But after 180sec my application get forcefully terminated by the Apple OS. Is there any way to run timer more than 180sec.

Comment: No you can not do it directly as it's limit from apple. You can save the time when app goes in background and when comes in foreground calculate the difference of both times and add it into your timer's last time.

Comment: Hey! Finally resolved the issue. By playing the silent audio in the background and that audio have a loop of -1 means inifinity. And it worked like a charm.. XD

Comment: You might be gonna ask a reason for background audio by apple. If you don't have a solid reason your app will be rejected.

Comment: Yes tiger, you are exactly right. But we will show the reason like after 500m of walking user will get a beep sound. I hope they will understand it.

Answer (score 0):

If time is of your concern and want to know exact after a specified interval , i suggest instead of using a timer you register for a local notification with fire date after your desired time interval.

If you need to perform a long task in background instead , you have to register it with system calling beginBackGroundTaskWithExpirationHandler method in this way :

```
    - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^{
        // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
        // stopped or ending the task outright.
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```

you can also refer to link here : [BackGroundTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Comment: Hey! thanks for your quick response. I had pedometer integrated in my app which notifies me that wheather device get shaked or not. And it uses the timer. Above code will work only for 3 min. Is there any way to make a recursion call for beginBackGroundTaskWithExpirationHandler method

Comment: why recursion call to beginBackGroundTaskWithExpirationHandler ? this gets you a token that allows you to run your task without os suspending your app. Register for events and do your background task in the block once you get the token

Comment: You have to approach this in a different way. Even if you make multiple calls to beginBackgroundTask you still only get 3 minutes background execution time per suspension, not 3 minutes per background task request

Comment: Hey! Finally resolved the issue. By playing the silent audio in the background and that audio have a loop of -1 means inifinity. And it worked like a charm.. XD